# Which countries transfered the most technology to Africa?

Tags: technology, africa

> China’s collaboration with African countries in technology transfer
> has been a topic of interest for many years. As one of the world’s
> leading technological powers, China has made significant strides in
> developing and implementing cutting-edge technology in various
> sectors. In recent years, China has increased its involvement in
> African countries, partnering with them to promote technological
> advancement and transfer.

https://thebftonline.com/2023/05/03/china-africa-collaboration-in-technology-transfer/

I was trying to find some statistics on the subject to see which countries did the most to help Africa by transferring technology, but couldn't find any statistics or even means to measure how much technology transfer is being done. Is there any research being done on this subject and what are the rankings?

Comment: How would you compare it?

Comment: How would you quantify that? Is a new paperclip design equal to a new electric car battery design?

Comment: @ohwilleke Maybe try to calculate the equivalent worth if you would have to buy that technology on the market.

Comment: @Sayaman: Also important: what do you mean by "technology"? "Physical Tools/Machinery", "Designs", and "Knowledge" can all be categorized as Technology depending on whom one asks.